# Get Data - from Snowflake in Power BI - Load never finishes - using ODBC - SAML Windows

Tags: powerbi, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've set up the 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC connections to Snowflake. When using the Get Data option in Power BI, I get a confirmation on login for both versions in the browser.

Your identity was confirmed and propagated to Snowflake ODBC driver. You can close this window now and go back where you started from.

I can see the view that I want to connect to and the data preview. When I select it, and click Load, it never finishes loading. Using the 32-bit ODBC connection, I also see a 400 Bad Request message in the browser. Using the 64-bit ODBC connection, I get several SAML windows (11 this time).

I also tried the Snowflake source, and I keep getting credential errors:

Details: "ODBC: ERROR [28000] Incorrect username or password was specified.
ERROR [28000] Incorrect username or password was specified."

My IT group suggested I post on Stack Overflow. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Jenny

Comment: I'm leaving this question on here, just in case anyone else has the same issue. However, once I went to Edit Queries, the data had actually loaded. It just never looked like it did.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the Snowflake VIEW in Power BI but cannot return data when previewing it, that sounds like a permission issue on the Snowflake side.  I'm not sure how you could have an incorrect username or password but be able to view the catalog unless something is being cached.  Can you view the error in Snowflake by checking your query history? If you see the error, then it's not a bad username/password.  If you don't see anything show up in Snowflake, then likely it is a bad username/password.

Next step is to make sure Power BI isn't caching bad credentials on you.  In PBI Desktop click Edit Queries>Data Source Settings. Select your Snowflake connection and click edit permissions, then under Credentials hit Edit or Delete and try adding your credentials back in again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when I tried to connect Power BI Desktop with Snowflake Datawarehouse and I performed the next steps to figure it out.

File>Options and settings>Data source settings>Select the permision that you would like to clear> Click on "Clear Permissions">Delete

When I went back to create the connection the issue was fixed.

Make sure that you are using the CORRECT credentials because you can block your Snowflake account during the next 15 min.